# Xerces - XmlString to Dom object

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I am trying to convert an Xml String to XML DOM object using Xerces (xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar).

But it seems that it provides only following methods, it does not offer a method that would take an XML string and convert it to an Object.

- `parse(File f)`
- `parse(InputSource is)`
- `parse(InputStream is)`
- `parse(String uri)`

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can convert the XML string to a `Reader`

```
java.io.StringReader xmlReader = new java.io.StringReader(xml);
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(xmlReader));
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the path specified), on Document line.